# How to check more than one condition in a method and do something based on it's return value

Tags: java

I am currently trying to work on a project that includes creating a BankAccount system. This system allows you to create a new bank account where you state who it belongs to, the balance, etc.

One of the methods is being able to withdraw money from the account. As well as this, you are able to check if the account has an overdraft or not.

For the `withdraw` method, I have to meet several conditions. These are the following:

- The Value must be above 0.0, meaning that withdrawals of below 0 won't happen
- The balance must NOT go below 0.0, UNLESS if the account HAS an overdraft.

At the moment, I have been able to make it so the method will return false, if the amount is below 0.0. This is shown below:

```
public boolean withdraw (double amount) {
    if (hasOverdraft) {
        this.balance -= amount;
        return true;
    } else if (amount > 0.0) {
        this.balance -= amount;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, I have tried several different things to make it work with the overdraft but can't seem to do it.

Bear in mind that at the end, the method needs to be able to:

- Allow the user to withdraw money providing the amount is above 0.0
- Allow the user to go into their overdraft (e.g. -100), PROVIDING that they actually have an overdraft.

The overdraft can  be checked with the following code:

```
if (hasOverdraft)
```

To check the code is working, we are using the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    BankAccount lewis = new BankAccount("1234", "Lewis", false);
    System.out.println(lewis);

    lewis.setBalance(200);
    System.out.println(lewis);
    lewis.withdraw(250);
    System.out.println(lewis);
}
```

The "false" for BankAccount is showing that the account doesn't have an overdraft. We will test it with both false and true.

Comment: What's the concrete problem? What have you tried?

Comment: can you post your `widthdraw()` method?

Comment: @user3170251 I posted the wrong method, my bad! I replaced the interest method with the withdraw method.

Comment: @JBNizet When I was trying to check more than one condition, it was ignoring other conditions and just wasn't working.

Comment: `if (amount > 0.0)` should be `if (amount > 0.0 && amount <= balance)`, no?

Comment: The rules say: "The balance must NOT go below 0.0". You're not even checking that. Start with that. Then improve the code to change the condition if the user has an averdraft. In this case, the rule would be "The balance must NOT go below -100". Both conditions are basically the same. The only different is the minimal value of the balance which is the overdraft. You can even use the exact same code in both cases if you're using 0 as overdraft when the user doesn't have one, and -100 when it has one.

Comment: @UnholySheep You have saved my life! Doing what you said has made everything work as expected. Thank you so much for your time and effort, you have made a difference in the world.

Answer (score 1):

> So much complexity in software comes from trying to make one thing do
>   two things.
>   *-Ryan Singer*

Your method does basically two things:

- **check if you can withdraw money** from the account (precondition), that's the case when overdrawing is allowed, or the balance won't become negative. The amount to withdraw should also be positive, and may not be zero (see comment by @forpas) - this can be part of the precondition, or just an argument validation step before.
- actually **withdraw the money** when you can (action).

Separating those two concerns makes the code more concise, avoids replication of the actual action, and allows for extracting the two things into separate reusable methods if called for later:

```
public boolean withdraw (double amount) {
    boolean canWithdraw = amount> 0 && (hasOverdraft || balance >= amount);

    if (canWithdraw ) {
        balance -= amount;
    }
    return canWithdraw;
}
```

As the commenters on the question already stated, you had a mistake in the precondition (checking the amount instead of the balance after withdrawing the amount).

Comment: I think `canWithdraw` must be changed to: `boolean canWithdraw = (amount > 0) && (hasOverdraft || balance >= amount);`

Comment: @forpas yes, this can be included into the precondition (I edited my answer accordingly), but in production code this would rather be an argument validation check (such as the `@Positive annotation` on the argument when using Java Validation / JSR-380).